# Django weighted percentage

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate a weighted percentage in a Django query.

This is an example of what my data looks like:

```
id      start_date  agency_id   area_id housetype_id    no_of_changed   price_change_percentage total
6716    2017-08-26  11          1       1               16              -0.09                   35
6717    2017-08-26  11          1       3               44              -0.11                   73
6718    2017-08-26  11          1       4               7               -0.1                    12
6719    2017-08-26  11          1       5               0               0                       4
6720    2017-08-26  11          1       6               0               0                       1
6721    2017-08-26  21          1       1               0               0                       1
6722    2017-08-26  34          1       1               0               0                       1
6723    2017-08-26  35          1       1               0               0                       1
6724    2017-08-26  38          1       1               0               0                       1
```

and this is my current code:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, ExpressionWrapper
from app.models import PriceChange

def weighted_percentage(area_id, date_range, agency_id, housetype):

    data = PriceChange.objects.filter(area_id=area_id,
                                      start_date__range=date_range,
                                      agency_id=agency_id,
                                      )

    if housetype:
        data = data.filter(housetype=housetype) \
            .values('start_date') \
            .annotate(price_change_total=ExpressionWrapper((F('price_change_percentage') * F('no_of_changed')) / F('total'), output_field=FloatField())) \
            .order_by('start_date')

    else:
        # what to do?
        pass

    x = [x['start_date'] for x in data]
    y = [y['price_change_total'] for y in data]

    return x, y
```

I figured out how to do the calculation when housetype is defined and I only need to data from one row. I can't figure out how to done when I need to calculate for multiple rows with the same start_date. I don't want a value for each row but for each start_date.

As an example (two rows with same start_date, area_id, agency_id but different housetype_ids):
    no_of_changed   price_change_percentage total
    16              -0.09                   35
    44              -0.11                   73

The calculation is in pseudocode:
`((no_of_changed[0] * price_changed_percentage[0]) + (no_of_changed[0] * price_changed_percentage[0])) / (total[0] + total[1]) = price_change_total`

`((16 * -0.09) + (44 * -0.11)/ (35 + 73) = -0.03148148`

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the expression in a Sum expression.

Add the following import:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```

Then add the following query

```
else:
    data = data.values('start_date') \
       .annotate(
           price_change_total=ExpressionWrapper(
               Sum(F('price_change_percentage') * F('no_of_changed')) / Sum(F('total')),
               output_field=FloatField()
           )
       ) \
       .order_by('start_date')
```

What is happening here is that when you use an aggregation expression such as `Sum` inside an `annotate()` call, it is translated into a `group_by` query in the database. All columns listed in the previous `values()` clause are used to create the `group_by` query.

See [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/12/06/how-to-create-group-by-queries.html) for further explanation and a breakdown of the resulting SQL query.

Comment: No, I'm tried to get the total for the start_date, not each row. I've tried to clarify the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Wessi thanks for the clarification. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Unfortunately, it's still not doing what I want it to. Instead of a weighted percentage like in the example: `((16 * -0.09) + (44 * -0.11)/ (35 + 73) = -0.03148148`  -- It's doing `((16 * -0.09) / 35) + ((44 * -0.11) / 73) = -0.10744422700587083` I.e the sum of the two percentages instead of a weighted average based on the value of total.

Comment: @Wessi I see. Sorry I didn't read you updated example close enough. All you need to do is wrap a `Sum()` around the numerator and denominator separately. I will update the answer

Comment: @Wessi Also `(((16 * -0.09) + (44 * -0.11)) / (35 + 73)` should be equal to `-0.0581`